# SQL query _count

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get an SQL query for the below data where I need to get the all the data from the customer table where there is more than 1 business unit assigned to a customer_id.

```
CustomerId  AccoutNo  UniqueCode  Owner p  AdminFlag  EmpId  Dept
----------  --------  ----------  -------  ---------  -----  ----
1                234         009      N        N         67   ABC
1                234         009      N        Y        232   ABC
1                234         009      Y        N         65   ABC
2                123         100      N        Y         73   PQR
2                123         100      N        N       7335   PQR
3                456         123      Y        N        633   ABC
3                789         123      Y        N       6363   ABC
1                456         009      N        Y       5674   PQR
```

Comment: there are no columns buisines unit in your table  ..

Comment: What field pertains to business units?

Comment: sorry that should be dept not Business unit so all the data from the customer table where there are more than 1 dept is assigned to a customer_id

Comment: interesting but there's no such row(i.e.your desired query would yield no row), by the way please edit your question what you want exactly, not comment.

Comment: Let me edit the table and put it this way

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect application of analytic functions, in this case the analytic function `count(distinct ...)`. In an inner query you compute how many distinct departments are present for each customer; run the subquery by itself, too, to see what it produces. Then the outer query simply selects the rows where the count is greater than 1.

```
select customer_id, account_no -- , ... - whatever other columns you must select
from   (
         select *, count(distinct dept) over (partition by customer_id) as ct
         from   customers
       )
where  ct > 1
;
```

Note - if `DEPT` can be `NULL`, those rows are not counted in the `count(distinct ...)` in any way. If `NULL` may be present and different handling is desired, you will need to state the requirement.